# Как сделать код более чистым в задаче на кратность чисел

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Хотелось бы уточнить, как в данной задаче можно сделать код еще более чистым и возможно ли?

Условие: *Золотая классика задачек на программирование! Напишите программу, которая для чисел, кратных 3, печатает «Яндекс», для чисел, кратных 5 — «Практикум», а для чисел, кратных одновременно 3 и 5 — «Яндекс.Практикум». В других случаях программа должна печатать само число.*

Моё решение:

```
public class Praktikum {
public static void 
main(String[] args) {
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        boolean isMultipleThree = i % 3 == 0;
        boolean isMultipleFive = i % 5 == 0;
        boolean isMultipleThreeAndFive = (i % 5 == 0) && (i % 3 == 0);
        
        if (isMultipleThree && !isMultipleFive && !isMultipleThreeAndFive) System.out.println("Яндекс") ;
        if (isMultipleFive && !isMultipleThree && !isMultipleThreeAndFive)  System.out.println("Практикум");
        if (isMultipleThreeAndFive) System.out.println("Яндекс.Практикум");
        if (!( isMultipleThree || isMultipleFive || 
              isMultipleThreeAndFive)) System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Много ненужных проверок. Кроме if есть ещё и else. А ``isMultipleThreeAndFive`` это ``isMultipleFive && isMultipleThree``, нет необходимости опять проверять остаток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        boolean isMultipleThree = i % 3 == 0;
        boolean isMultipleFive = i % 5 == 0;

        if (isMultipleFive && isMultipleThree) {
            System.out.println("Яндекс.Практикум");
        } else if (isMultipleThree) {
            System.out.println("Яндекс");
        } else if (isMultipleFive) {
            System.out.println("Практикум");
        } else {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно "вычислить" некоторый код и использовать `switch` относительно этого кода:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    String s = switch(i % 15 == 0 ? 15 : i % 3 == 0 ? 3 : i % 5 == 0 ? 5 : i) {
        case  3 -> "Яндекс";
        case  5 -> "Практикум";
        case 15 -> "Яндекс.Практикум";
        default -> Integer.toString(i);
    };
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Также можно "заготовить" массив строк и выводить значение в зависимости от остатка по модулю 15:

```java
String[] arr = {
    "Яндекс.Практикум", null, null, "Яндекс", null, //  0 ..  4 
    "Практикум", "Яндекс", null, null, "Яндекс",    //  5 ..  9
    "Практикум", null, "Яндекс", null, null         // 10 .. 14
};

for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    System.out.println(Optional.ofNullable(arr[i % 15]).orElse(Integer.toString(i)));
}
```